# cant get $_POST data to strip special characters

Tags: php, strip-tags

I'm under the impression that $_POST is a global  that includes all data from inputs in the post-data and session properties so when the submit button is pressed with is set it takes all the data and strips all the crap out before it sends it to the database/email/ect for obvious reasons. I placed echos before and after the action. so it seems to go right over it. an error

> strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/buckeye/website/test1.php on line 58

but as far as I can see $_POST is the string. So why is it not working?

Line 58:

```
$_POST = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST))))));
```

Comment: Can you tell us what it is exactly that you're trying to do/avoid?

Comment: If you're trying to avoid an SQL injection, you're going about it all wrong. If so, just use a prepared statement. If you're wanting to avoid an possible XSS injection, you're also going about it wrong.

Comment: strip all special characters, and html code,unicode and other codes from all inputs before data is submitted to database and emails

Comment: This seems a closely related repost of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53641988/1415724). Edit: To which I noticed you deleted just now. (viewable only by 10k+).

Comment: Personally, I think you're going to run into more problems later on with your database stuff.

Comment: `strip_tags($_POST)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Your fundamental issue is `strip_tags` only works on strings. `$_POST` is an array. You have to run `strip_tags` on *each* item within the `$_POST` array. (Side note: individual items may *themselves* also be arrays, in some cases...)
2. Escaping user data should be done on *display*, not when saving to the database. You should save the user's submission exactly as it was submitted, in cases you make a mistake in your escaping that you'd like to fix.
3. `strip_tags` won't protect your database anyways (for example, it's not going to stop a `'` from breaking things, as your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection). You should be using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

And yet again, the error is pretty clear. `$_POST` is an array, not a single string.

If you want to `strip_tags` of each entry in `$_POST`, you'll need a loop like that:

```
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        $_POST[$key] = strip_tags($value);
    }
```